# Connections Cloud - Cannot display credentials for Internal App

Tags: ibm-connections

We have moved our development to CA1 Connections Cloud environment and started setting up our application.

I create a new Internal Application in the admin interface with OAuth2. After that I tried retrieving the application credentials using the Show Credentials button.

This resulted in a page refresh and all I got was an unstyled html page with navigation only, no other messages and no credentials. After clicking the back button I get an error message "**Unable to fetch credential info.**"

Clicking Reset Credentials or changing auth type to OAuth1 behaves the same.

Is there anything I can do to work around this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I will have someone look at this on my team

Comment: opened a defect on this feature