# Connections Cloud: Authentication for Integrated App

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

We are currently developing an app for Connections Cloud using the service_menu extension point to navigate to our app, which then integrates the Connections nav-bar for a seemless experience for the end user.

However, requests to our system have to be authenticated. The user has at that point logged in to Connections and I feel it would be detrimental to user experience if we ask him to provide his credentials again during the OAuth dance to retrieve his token. From [the documentation](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Toolkit+docs#action=openDocument&res_title=Configuring_single_signon_for_integrated_applications_sbt&content=sdkcontent) I understand, that OAuth and SAML are my only options here. How can I solve authentication withouth bothering the user to provide his credentials again and make the integration appear as seemless as possible in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, you will need to ask for your user's identity some how.  if you redirect the user back to smartcloud using the oauth dance, you still need identity.  From a 3rd party perspective, it'd be best if you integrate via SAML with the customer's IDP

Comment: As in this related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431966/connections-cloud-cannot-display-credentials-for-internal-app 
OAuth is currently not usable, because I'm unable to retrieve the credentials. Are there any updates on this? Or maybe a workaround?

Comment: the fix is going through regression, I can't share a date for delivery. please open a pmr by emailing support, and asking for the OAuth credentials for your application.